# How to import-export application's data?

Tags: android, file-io

I'm building an application that calculates the fuel consumption of cars. The datas are saved in a file, and i'm planning to add support of import/export feature in the app(i often flash the phone).
How can i make this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to write the data to the sdcard since it isn't touched when you flash your phone

For sdcard io see: [Writing a file to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard)

Comment: And what about importing the file ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like Fredrik Leijon said write to the SDCard(it's a good link there) and correspondingly read from there to 'import' your data.