# How to store and retrieve xml response in sqlite datadase

Tags: android

i want to store xml response in sqlite and retrieve  when data coming from server from it my response is following..

```
<soap:Envelope><soap:Body><Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResponse><Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResult><xs:schema id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Table1"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="ReturnValue" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="UserId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram><NewDataSet><Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><ReturnValue>100</ReturnValue><UserId>bc43c80d-061e1</UserId></Table1></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram></Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResult></Login_ValidateAuthenticatedUserResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the xml first and then store the fields in your sqlite. Your database schema should be according the info that you want to be stored.
[Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) give you the various parsing options.
I really dont know why would you want to store the file and parse it later. Even if you want to store, then why store in database? There are other [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) too. You should store the file on external storage and then use it later whenever you want to. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard) link gives you how to write a file to external storage.

Comment: No i want to parse it after store. thanx bro.

Comment: Storing a file in a database is unheard of! Anyways check my updated answer.