# How to save files at phone storage

Tags: android

I want to save files to the device memory when SD card is inserted into the phone. Calling

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

returns SD card folder located at mnt/sdcard.
Phone storage folder is located at mnt/sdcard2. Is there a way to get path to mnt/sdcard2 programmatically to download files there?

Comment: `Phone storage folder is located at mnt/sdcard2.` Usually no. what device are you working on ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal. check the docs has a code snippet.

Comment: I'm using Zopo zp900. It has 2 Gb of it's own memory and a slot for SD card.

Comment: Here's a very good answer to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard