# C# How to save an images to SD card?

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin for Android. I load an image and put it in ImageView, then I edit the image. Next I want to save that image to SD card.

Anyone know how to save the image into SD card because I only can find it in Java Android. I already try to convert the code from Java to C# but still get an error.

Any help, thanks in advance.

---

I get an error at `InputStream iS = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);` as the error is "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'Java.IO.InputStream'"

Here's the code:

```
Java.IO.File path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File (path, "Icon.png");

try {
    path.Mkdirs();
    InputStream iS = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
    OutputStream oS = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[iS.Available()];
    iS.Read(data);
    oS.Write(data);
    iS.Close();
    oS.Close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? and what is the error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a file to sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard)

Comment: @Raptor I edited the question and put the code that I already convert it from java to c#

Answer (score 3):

I use this to save the captured photo to sdcard:

```cs
public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
{
    // Save the image JPEG data to the SD card
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    File dataDir = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
    if (data!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dataDir + "/" + PICTURE_FILENAME);
            outStream.Write(data);
            outStream.Close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("SIMPLECAMERA", e.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("SIMPLECAMERA", e.Message);
        }
        File file = new File(dataDir + "/" + PICTURE_FILENAME);
        try 
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.CanonicalPath);
            // Read the camera model and location attributes
            exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagModel);
            float[] latLng = new float[2];
            exif.GetLatLong(latLng);
            // Set the camera make
            exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagMake, “My Phone”);
            exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagDatetime, 
            System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("SIMPLECAMERA", e.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "No Image Captured", ToastLength.Long);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @eMi  how to use the parameter data and camera?

Comment: @syamilsynz use `MemoryStream` to convert the image to a byte array. there should be dozens of examples in the internet.

Answer (score -1):

found the answer, credit to Mohd Riyaz.

```
var yourImageView = new ImageView(this); //Your image view
        var fetchedDrawable = yourImageView.Drawable;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)fetchedDrawable;
        var bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("AbsolutePath_File", FileMode.Create))
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
        }
```

Comment: and i use Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + "icon.png" instead of "AbsolutePath_File"