# Getting the data path of assets folder in android

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate Tesseract in android. So I have to initialize the tesseract with trained data by calling baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang). DATA_PATH is the path of traineddata.lang file which is to be put in assests folder then in  tessdata folder in String format.But I am not able to find a way to do this and getting this error repeatedly.

> 02-20 19:26:17.574: W/dalvikvm(4427): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41cf9da0)
>   02-20 19:26:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-20 19:26:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(4427): Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 4427 
> 02-20 19:26:17.584: >E/AndroidRuntime(4427): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path must contain subfolder tessdata! 
> 02-20 19:26:17.584: >E/AndroidRuntime(4427):   at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:283)

I have already used these and not able to proceed further.

- String DATA_PATH = "file:///assets/tessdata/eng.traineddata";
- String DATA_PATH = "file://android_assest/tessdata/eng.traineddata";

also using both with URI also.

Answer (score 0):

A quite from https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

> You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original
>   filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way
>   as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of
>   bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for
>   textures and game data.

So you can't get path on asset file, as well as it would be inside apk. In order to get path of file, you can [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets) file and [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard) on SD card.

Comment: I don't have to take input from the file myself but only have to pass the path as String format  and the in-built function will do the processing what it have to do. Also apk might have been saved in internal memory of the phone.

Comment: Please read what I wrote. Read asset file and write it to sd card and you will be able to get a path to that.

Comment: What if there is no SD Card in the phone?