# react-native android - how to save pdf to the android file system

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am creating an application very similar to whatsapp. I want to know how to save pdf files and images to the android file system?

Comment: Did you try investigating a bit?. Relevant stack post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard

Comment: Yes I did. Thats link is for android. I am looking for how to do it using react-native-android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save pdf to android file system and then view PDF - react-native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662309/how-to-save-pdf-to-android-file-system-and-then-view-pdf-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs). The writeFile method allows you to write files to your application's file system.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The problem seems to be saving the file. Check out this post for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662309/how-to-save-pdf-to-android-file-system-react-native Thanks.